# there is no result my javascript array WHY?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i push data array i can see it in array but  out of function there is no data in array why ??

function keyWordsearch() {

```
        var musicIDs = [];
        gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyB2O-w22OSJVSKPhAYsK_zxX7FsThM0mhE');
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {
            idlist = '';


            var q = $('#querySerach').val();
            $("#result").empty();
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet',
                maxResults: 3,

            });

            request.execute(function (response) {

                for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

                    var musicid2 = response.items[i].id.videoId;

                    musicIDs.push(musicid2);

                   // i push data array i can see it in array but  out of function there is no data in array why ?? ------

                    var pID = '#myPlayerID';
                    var ratio = '4/3';

                }

            });

        });
        alert(musicIDs[1]); // here is musicID[1] return undefined
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are *asynchronous*, so you have to do the `alert` inside the response function where the api is called. In this case inside the `request.execute(function (response) {`

```
request.execute(function (response) {

            for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

                var musicid2 = response.items[i].id.videoId;

                musicIDs.push(musicid2);

                var pID = '#myPlayerID';
                var ratio = '4/3';

            }

            alert(musicIDs[1]);
}
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Answer edited, thanks

Comment: thank you to help. yes i can get data this case , but i need this array in another function.but when i use this array in another function ,no data return

Comment: You need to call the another function inside the response function to ensure this array has the correct data or use the promises to execute other function when the first function has finished his ajax request. See the more info link.

Comment: @AnılSarı: This issue is thoroughly discussed in the linked question and its answers.

Comment: i dont understand :/